# Excel VBA Input Date and then Output Date in UK Format

Tags: vba, date, excel

I've made a simple macro to move data from one tab to another and add a date to simplify the process we had of constructing a journal.

However, when I ask for a date to be input - VBA does it's usual trick of turning your date into a US date. What I need is for the user to input a UK date and the output be the same UK date - however, if I input a UK date it comes out as a US date.

The only way round this I can think of is to enter the date in US format and the use `Format(str, "dd/mm/yyyy")` to output the date in UK format but this is not ideal.

A simpler method would be a great help as the macro is for the team rather than just myself.

```
Dim wb As Workbook, wk1 As Worksheet, wk2 As Worksheet, rng As Range, str As String

Sub Journal()
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wk1 = ActiveSheet
Set wk2 = wb.Sheets("CBCS Journal")

str = InputBox(Prompt:="What date would you like to post this journal for?", _
    Title:="Enter the posting date", Default:=Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy"))
For i = 1 To wk1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 9
wk2.Range("B" & i + 1).Value = str

End Sub
```

Comment: It isn't clear what your issue is exactly. What "usual trick"? Please show some example input, desired output, current output, and point out how the current output differs from the desired. [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) always helps, so do screenshots.

Comment: The "usual trick" is that is changes all dates to be US dates when storing them. What I would like it to input a UK date in the inputbox and also have the output as the same UK date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Dim str As String
Dim splitStr() As String
Dim strFormat As String
Dim d As Date

'Your preferred date format
strFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"

'Get string representing date
str = InputBox(Prompt:="What date would you like to post this journal for?", _
               Title:="Enter the posting date", Default:=Format(Now, strFormat))

'Parse the date string
splitStr = Split(str, "/")
d = DateSerial(CInt(splitStr(2)), CInt(splitStr(1)), CInt(splitStr(0)))
'Display it in the proper format
With Range("A1")
    .Value = d
    .NumberFormat = strFormat
End With
```