# Day and month values swapped when displaying date on cell

Tags: vba

I've got the following code

```
Sub test()

my_date = "01/09/2021  7:42"
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = my_date

End Sub
```

This returns the following result

[image]

Why does it show in the cell "09/01/2021" rather than "01/09/2021" like on my original variable?

Comment: Please see the following post which treats this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29511732/excel-vba-input-date-and-then-output-date-in-uk-format

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it this way

```
Sub test()

Dim my_date As Date
my_date = "01/09/2021  7:42"
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = my_date

End Sub
```